# DFS in adjacency matrix

Tags: java, stack, depth-first-search, adjacency-matrix

I am having trouble with my DFS it is giving out the wrong traversal. I also need to get the first encounter of the DFS and save it so it can be printed for later. The first encounter would be 1 2 6 7 4 3 5 8

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.*;

public class DFS {

private Stack<Integer> stack;

String line;
int row = 0;
static int size = 0;

public DFS(){

stack = new Stack<Integer>();

}

public void dfs(int adjMatrix[][], int vert)
{
int number_of_nodes = adjMatrix[vert].length - 1;

int visited[] = new int[number_of_nodes + 1];   
int element = vert;     
int i = vert;       
System.out.println(element + "\t");
visited[vert] = 1;      
stack.push(vert);

while (!stack.isEmpty())
{
    element = stack.peek();
    i = element;    
while (i <= number_of_nodes)
{

        if (adjMatrix[element][i] == 1 && visited[i] == 0)
    {

            stack.push(i);

            visited[i] = 1;
            element = i;

            i = 1;

            System.out.print(element + "\t");

        continue;
        }
        i++;
}
    stack.pop();



 }
}


public static int[][] create2DIntMatrixFromFile(String filename) throws                 Exception {
int[][] matrix = null;

BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

String line;
int row = 0;
int size = 0;

while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] vals = line.trim().split(" ");

    // Lazy instantiation.
    if (matrix == null) {
        size = vals.length;
        matrix = new int[size+1][size+1];
    }

    for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
        matrix[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(vals[col]);
    }

    row++;
}

return matrix;
}

public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
String str = "";
int size = matrix.length;

if (matrix != null) {
    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
        str += " ";
        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
            str += String.format("%2d",  matrix[row][col]);
            if (col < size - 1) {
                str += "  ";
            }
        }
        if (row < size - 1) {
            str += "\n";
            for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                   // str += " ";
                }
                if (col < size - 1) {
                    //str += "+";
                }
            }
            str += "\n";
        } else {
            str += "\n";
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(str);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{


 int[][] matrix = null;

 try {
     matrix = create2DIntMatrixFromFile("sample.txt");
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }

    System.out.println("The DFS Traversal for the graph is given by ");
    DFS dfs = new DFS();
    dfs.dfs(matrix, size);
    System.out.println(" ");
    printMatrix(matrix);                    
   }    

}
```

The output for this is

```
The DFS Traversal for the graph is given by 
0   
1   5   4   6   2   3   7    
 0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0

   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0

   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0

   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0

   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0

   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0

   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0

   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0

   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

The traversal is suppose to be

1 2 6 5 7 3 4 8

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your DFS code has several problems. Most importantly `stack.pop()` is called after the neighbors have been pushed onto the stack. Therefore, the `pop` removes one of the neighbors instead of the currently processed element. The neighbors of the ith nodes are the non-zero entries in the ith row (or ith column, since the graph is undirected). But your code does not iterate over a fixed column or row but seems to jump around the matrix. It's not clear to me what you want to do there. It would be helpful if you would add comments to describe your intention.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you could specify what you mean by "first encounter". You specified the traversal you want to obtain as "1 2 6 5 7 3 4 8". This makes sense for me from the graph. For the "first encounter", you specified "1 2 6 7 4 3 5 8". I don't understand how this order should be obtained. If by "first encounter" you mean the first time a node is seen (i.e. pushed onto the stack), I get a different order from the graph. Please specify what definition of "first encounter" you are using and whether the example you provided matches the definition.